Proving the projection of a manifold on two coordinates is a one-dimensional submanifold
I have a smooth properly embedded submanifold $G \subset P^6$ (here $P$ denotes the strictly positive real numbers so $P^6$ would be the strictly positive orthant of $R^6$). Denote a generic point $p \in G$ by $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,Y_1,Y_2)$. From separate considerations I know there is a smooth, strictly increasing function $f : P \rightarrow P$ such that, for all $p \in G$, we must have $Y_2 = f(Y_1)$. My ultimate aim is to prove that the projection $\pi$ of $G$ onto the last two coordinates is a one-dimensional submanifold of $P^2$.
My approach: Right now all I know is that $\pi(G)$ must be a subset of the graph of $f$. I can't conclude it is a submanifold of $P^2$. However, if I knew that $\iota_5$, the projection onto the fifth coordinate, was an open map, then I could conclude that $\iota_5 (G)$ was open in $P$, thus that the graph of $f$ is a one-dimensional submanifold of $P^2$.
Question: Is my approach correct or am I making too much of this simple scenario?
If my approach is correct then I have another question: Suppose I impose the condition, at each $p \in G$, that there exists a neighborhood $U \subset G$ of $p$ on which $X_3,X_4,Y_2$ can each be solved for as functions of $(X_1,X_2,Y_1)$ (say by using the implicit function theorem). Then could I conclude that, locally, $G$ is a graph and that the projection $\iota_5 : G \rightarrow P$ is a submersion, hence open? Finally, wouldn't that then imply that $\iota_5 (G)$ was an open subset of $P$ and give me the desired conclusion?
Edit I failed to specify, in this particular case, that $G$ is actually a three-dimensional level set; it's the set of solutions to three equations. My apologies to @While I Am for this omission.

Do you want the image of $G$ under $\pi$ to be an immersed or embedded submanifold? I do not think the latter is guaranteed.

Embedded, definitely. I was under the impression (could be wrong) that the graph of a smooth function on an open set was an embedded manifold. Where do you think my error is? Thanks for commenting.

I don't believe that this is enough to guarantee that the projection is an embedded submanifold. The issue is that you in the setting of your question, you are not guaranteed that the image of the projection is a "well-behaved" subset of the graph.
For example, the image could be a countable subset of the graph with an accumulation point, which as a manifold has the discrete topology, but is not discrete in the subspace topology and hence not an embedded submanifold.
To be concrete, I will describe an analogous situation in $P^3$. Set
$$G = \left\{\left(1-\frac{n}{2}, 1- \frac{n}{2}, n\right) : n \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}\right\} \cup \{(1,1,1)\}$$
Then $G$ is a properly embedded zero-dimensional submanifold of $P^3$.
To verify this, we can check that if $C$ is compact in $P^3$, then it is bounded, thus can contain only finitely many elements of $G$, so if $i : G \hookrightarrow P^3$ is the embedding, $i^{-1}(C)$ is finite, thus compact. So the immersion is proper, and to see that $G$ is embedded we need only observe that $G$'s subspace topology is discrete (and if you require your manifolds to be second-countable, we have that $G$ is countable).
Moreover, the first two coordinates satisfy the relation $y = x$, so $G$ satisfies the hypotheses as given in your problem.
However, the projection of $G$ onto the first two coordinates is the set:
$$\pi_{1,2}(G) = \left\{\left(1-\frac{n}{2},1-\frac{n}{2}\right) : n \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}\right\} \cup \{(1,1)\}$$
which has an accumulation point at $(1,1)$, hence is not an embedded submanifold, as $\pi_{1,2}(G)$'s subspace topology would need to be discrete, but it has an accumulation point at $(1,1)$.
By relabelling the coordinates and extending into $P^6$ via an embedding into a suitable 3-dimensional subset (e.g., $\{(1,1,1,a,b,c) : a,b,c\in P\}$) this can be taken to be a counterexample to your specific conjecture.

Thanks for your time in composing an answer, but I have a couple of questions. In my case $G$ is a three dimensional solution set to three equations: I'm sorry I did not put that in, I will correct it. Second, though, I thought that my additional condition of $G$ being, locally, a graph at each point and thus $\iota_5$ being an open map, would still yield the projection as the graph of a smooth function on an open set. I will have to examine your answer closely to see where I have gone wrong but, again, thanks. I will either mark as correct or comment again with my questions.

I've looked at your answer in more detail; very clever, I see what you are doing. However, part of my question (I believe I made this clear but I could be wrong) involved an additional assumption that the projection $\iota_5$ was an open map, so that $\iota_5 (G)$ would be an open subset of $P$. Wouldn't your example violate this? The image of $G$ by this projection is not open in the usual topology of $P$, it's a set of discrete points. Again, I could be missing something, thanks for your help.
